# When should "those" be used in place of "the"?

Tags: word-usage

In the following, the the word "those" is used, but it seems like "the" could be used fine instead:

> In this case, the best we can do is use the Weak Inside View — visualizing the causal process — to produce loose qualitative conclusions about only **those** issues where there seems to be lopsided support. (From [here](http://lesswrong.com/lw/hzu/model_combination_and_adjustment/))

Also, here:

> “If sins of omission have been committed here, it is with the recognition that Pandora’s Box was full indeed and there is space in these pages to discuss only **those** infectious agents that have demonstrated a past or present capacity for creating plagues or pandemics, or which now appear to be emerging as serious threats in the future” (From *Global Catastrophic Risks*).

Google [says](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=those%20deifne&oq=those%20deifne&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3142j0j4) that "those" is plural for "that," and that "that" can be "used in singling out someone or something and ascribing a distinctive feature to them." This is what the above quotations did, making them correct English.

However, I have not found any source saying whether or not "those" is required to be used instead of "that." It is quite difficult to google for this, due to the ubiquity of the word "the."

So, when should "those" be used in place of "the" and when are they both acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, the pronoun "that", and therefore "those", are used for singling something out. Remember the distinction between 'these' (nearby) and 'those' (further away). There is a sense of pointing, e.g. "See those over there?"

> *In this case, the best we can do is use the Weak Inside View —*
>   *visualizing the causal process — to produce loose qualitative*
>   *conclusions about only *those* issues where there seems to be lopsided*
>   *support.*

In that sentence we can see the advantage of "those". The writers are *distancing* themselves from the issues with lopsided support.

> [distance yourself from sth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/distance-yourself-from-sth)  — phrasal verb with distance
>
> /ˈdɪs.təns/ verb
>
> › to become or seem less involved or connected with something:
>
> *The leader has recently distanced himself from the extremists in the party.*

I hope this explains it.

Comment: Would omitting "those" still be correct, but just slightly change the meaning?

Comment: Yes, you can remove _those_ in the examples you have given without really changing the meaning much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the use of "those" in your first example is actually correct.  Replacing "those" with "the" might still be incorrect.  It seems that this sentences works better by omitting "those."  It seems better to say, "...only about issues in which there seems to be lopsided support."

Hopefully, we get some more perspective on this post.

Comment: It’s perfectly correct and natural. _The_ instead of _those_ would be slightly less natural, but still quite grammatical. Leaving out _those_ altogether would also be both natural and grammatical.